# How do I add 'last' to the last article?

Tags: jquery

```
$("body.page-template-testimonials-php article:last-child").addClass("last");
```

That's the code I'm using to target the last article on the page. However, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the markup: http://pastebin.com/m6nHxEQh

Comment: You could use this selector: `$("article:last")`

Comment: Thanks JCOC611. I just tried that but it didn't work.Ah, nevermind it works. Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you adding this class in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you used:

```
$("#content article:last").addClass("last");
```

Since I don't see the body.page-template-testimonials-php class anywhere.

Comment: +1 Even if it did exist (the class), wouldn't it be..hmm...too long and ugly?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's the class created by Wordpress for custom page templates.

Comment: @JCOC611 Indeed. Since using the '#' selector uses the native getElementById() JavaScript method, it's also faster. Some good jQuery rule-of-thumb performance guidelines can be found here: http://bit.ly/12yFxO

Comment: @John Use `$('body.page-template-testimonials-php #content article:last').addClass("last");` instead, then, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body.page-template-testimonials-php article').last().addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .eq() to filter before applying class:

```
$("body.page-template-testimonials-php article").eq(-1).addClass("last");
```